# To find distance in QGIS

Tags: qgis, distance, network

I'm looking for a solution in QGIS for:
the distance measurements from each and every cell site (blue point) back to the Exchange(point) that they are connected with. We need to take the shortest path from the cell site to the Exchange, but it has to go along our design path (obviously, use the civils and direction that we already worked on).

In the picture below  the Blue circles are the cell sites and the Black lines are the Cell Fibre.
We need the measurement of the red line which is the total distance from the Cell Site to the Exchange.
The BLUE LINE is the Exchange Fibre.
[image]

This will be a very slow, manual process unless we can come up with a way to query this in QGIS?

So to clarify even more: for Cell #1 and Cell #2, we need distance to the exchange

Cell #1 distance is: A + B + C

Cell #2 distance is: B + C

Do you have any idea what we can do to solve this using QGIS automatically?
[image]